# Woocommerce - expose ajax data to custom javascript

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to build a custom Woocommerce product list page - which I've got set up fine.

However, when I try to set up AJAX add to cart, I cannot figure out how to localize my script with the ajax endpoints for woocommerce.

I found a snippet that makes sense

```
$.post(wc_add_to_cart_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace('%%endpoint%%', 'add_to_cart'), data, function (response) {
```

However, I can't figure out how to expose wc_add_to_cart_params to my script. All the woocommerce docs I've found expect you to do hook shenanigans to modify what they're already putting out, but I don't want to do that. I want to make my own template and manually fire this off.

So
1 How do I localize the various woocommerce endpoitns into my script? (I understand how to use localize_script, but I dont' know how to grab the ajax endpoints in my functions.php file.

2 Is there legitimate documentation for working with woocommerce this way? The docs on their site seem real bad, and intended only for very minor modification or modification that stays within the hook paradigm. (which I absolutely hate doing as I find it incredibly finicky and more error prone than just building the page and calling data like you would with any other WP objects).

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who runs into this.

I ended up solving this not by using WC Ajax, but by writing my own Ajax handler and manually adding to cart there. The function isn't finished and still needs proper response handling, but it's enough to get you going if you have the same hangup as I did.

```
function cabinets_add_to_cart() {
    ob_start();

    $productID = $_POST['productID'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $passed_validation = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $productID, $quantity);
    $product_status = get_post_status($productID);

    if( $passed_validation && WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $productID, $quantity) && 'publish' === $product_status) {
        do_action( 'woocommerce_aax_added_to_cart', $productID);
        wc_add_to_cart_message($productID);
    }
    else {
        $data = array(
            'error' => true,
            'product_url' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', get_permalink($productID), $productID)
        );

        wp_send_json($data);
    }
    die();
}
```